# How to get the coordinates inside the polygon using python

Tags: qgis, polygon, pyqgis, coordinates

I have a polygon and using this code snippet we can get the coordinates boundary of the polygon.

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
aLayer = canvas.currentLayer()
coord = feat.geometry().asPoygon()
```

So if i want to get the coordinates inside the polygon also how can i do that using python?

Comment: what do you mean by getting the coordinates? Be more specific !

Comment: A polygon is defined as at least one outer boundary and 0..n inner boundaries (holes). You want the inner boundaries (holes) or a point inside the polygon?

Comment: @nickves i want the points  falling inside the polygon.

Answer (score 2):

## A point inside a polygon

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
aLayer = canvas.layer(0)  # or code to select the layer of interest
for f in aLayer.getFeatures():
    geom = f.geometry()  
    p = geom.pointOnSurface()
    print p.asPoint()
```

## Get Inner Rings

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
aLayer = canvas.layer(0)  # or code to select the layer of interest
for f in aLayer.getFeatures():
    geom = f.geometry()
    if len(geom.asPolygon()) > 1 : # we have inner rings
      print geom.asPolygon()[1:]
```

Comment: i am getting only only one point but i need all the points falling inside the polygon.

Comment: What do you mean? How many points do you want? You mean you have **another** point layer and you want to count how many points are inside your polygons?

Comment: If you want the points falling inside the polygon then it is an infinite number of points.

Comment: @nickves i have raster layer and i want to calculate the pixels values. For that i want to  find the points in the polygon that intersects with the raster.